# Unity-How can I enlarge the sprite to avoid the movement of the character when the pivot change?

Tags: unity, animation, sprites

Changing the pivot to custom on all of the sprites is not a viable option for me

Video showing the problem:

https://youtu.be/YpAdamkbhFA

Comment: Can you explain why changing the pivot on each frame is not viable? Any other solution I can think of would require at least as much manual work as pivot changes, if not more.

Comment: There are a lot of sprites with a lot of different centers . I tried before to change it manually but a slight difference in the center in this case is noticeable and it no longer looks fluid in addition to that it will have to be done in more than 2000 sprites

Comment: Sounds like you have 2000 sprites' worth of work to do then. If even "a slight difference is noticeable" then you'll need the accuracy of manual adjustment - any automated process is likely to make mistakes.